# How to Launch Standalone SDK Manager in Android Studio(version 2.1.1); SDK version(23)?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

While updating few latest packages in my Android Studio 2.1.1, two of the packages need me to 'Exit Android Studio and Launch Standalone SDK Manager' (see image link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ueRW.png

How do I do that? 
Also, Launch Standalone SDK Manager Option in the Tools> Android> SDKManager file doesn't work.
Please help!

Comment: Did you try to lunch using cmd or terminal ?

Comment: When I click on it, the terminal opens for for half a second and closes immediately. How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk from command prompt and launch SDK Manager.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can open it from your sdk path which in my case is

> C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Double click on `SDK Manager.exe` and it will open standalone SDK manager, refer **attached Screenshot**.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, found it! I double-clicked. It didn't open. Could you help with that?

Comment: Double click on "SDK Manager.exe" it will open in new window, where you can download stuff that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can no longer open the standalone SDK or AVD Manager in the later versions of Android Studio.  At least, that appears to be the case for for Android Studio  3.0 beta versions.  I did read a post where someone claimed that the standalone versions have been deprecated.  Navigating to Android Studio SDK location and double clicking on either "SDK Manager" or "AVD Manager" doesn't bring up the standalone managers anymore.  I believe that's the way its intended to work.  I have read that some people have downloaded and installed the Android SDK independent of Android Studio and are able to bring up a standalone version.  I've not tried this since I'm not exactly sure where one would get an official Android SDK. The official site has it bundled with android studio. They only reason I was trying to bring up a standalone version was that someone suggested that if it could be used to install the Oriel Google play x86 emulator, which apparently doesn't give the bogus "Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: goldfish_battery_read: Bad offset .. " errors.  It's just a nuisance error message so I wasn't that interested in seeing this that would eliminate that bogus error message.  I've installed that emulator using the SDK manager in Android Studio itself, but I'm not able to configure an emulator that uses it using the built in AVD Manager.  Not sure why, but it is after all a beta version of Android Studio.